# print txt file direct to printer aspx.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

i'm using following method to create txt file, and now I don't know how to send this file direct to printer.I want when user click on button_click event, txt file to be printed without print preview...etc.application is web deployed

```
 public void Print()
   {

    string path = @"c:\Restaurant\kitchen.txt";


    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
        {



                if (Label53.Text == "4")
                {
                  String s = Label47.Text;

                   s = String.Format(s.Replace("S", "С").Replace("U", "У").Replace("P", "П").Replace("A", "А"));


                    sw.WriteLine(s);



                }
             }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Your `String.Format` seems unnecessary since you don't format _anything_.

Comment: yeah, I forget to delete that

Comment: @Soner Gönül Is possible now to print this .txt file direct to printer?

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you.

Comment: @birthname , one question more, my app is web deployed, app is made for tablet, could this method somehow from tablet read thermal printer, that printer has no IP address. and print on him?

Comment: is that possible to keep searching a solution or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible...

First you to add Reference `System.Drawing` to the project.After that you need to use:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
```

I will show it for console application, you can convert it to asp.net easily.

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetStockObject(int fnObject);

    private static string stringToPrint;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
        ReadFile(doc);
        doc.PrintPage += doc_PrintPage;
        doc.Print();
    }

    private static void ReadFile(PrintDocument printDocument1)
    {
        string docName = "Test.txt";
        string docPath = @"c:\";
        printDocument1.DocumentName = docName;
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(docPath + docName, FileMode.Open))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            stringToPrint = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    static void doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        int charactersOnPage = 0;
        int linesPerPage = 0;

        // Sets the value of charactersOnPage to the number of characters  
        // of stringToPrint that will fit within the bounds of the page.
        e.Graphics.MeasureString(stringToPrint, Font.FromHfont(GetStockObject(0)),
            e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic,
            out charactersOnPage, out linesPerPage);

        // Draws the string within the bounds of the page
        e.Graphics.DrawString(stringToPrint, Font.FromHfont(GetStockObject(0)), Brushes.Black,
            e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

        // Remove the portion of the string that has been printed.
        stringToPrint = stringToPrint.Substring(charactersOnPage);

        // Check to see if more pages are to be printed.
        e.HasMorePages = (stringToPrint.Length > 0);
    }
```

This was the code. I'm using `GetStockObject` just to create Font you can use another custom Font, if you want.

Comment: @birthname , one question more, my app is web deployed, app is made for tablet, could this method somehow from tablet read thermal printer, that printer has no IP address. and print on him? - 
is that possible to keep searching a solution or not

Comment: the policy of the website is to ask question one by one. If you have another question just create new question, someone will answer you.